# Accessing spring-boot application.properties elements in Junit ClassRule

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I would like to access resource/properties file elements (in the below code its's `cardEventTopic` and `cardEventErrorTopic` constants) in a junit static class rule. Is there any way to achieve this? As the elements are already exists in the properties file, I don't want to put them as static constant in the test files. Also the `@Value("${}")` wouldn't work with static context. Any help if there is a way to make this work.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = PaymentAccountUpdaterApplication.class,
                webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-messaging.properties")
public class CardIntegrationTest {

    private final static String cardEventTopic = "TP.PRF.CARDEVENTS";
    private final static String cardEventErrorTopic = "TP.PAYMENTS.CARDEVENTS.ERRORS";

    @ClassRule
    public static KafkaEmbedded kafkaEmbedded =
            new KafkaEmbedded(1, false, cardEventTopic, cardEventErrorTopic);
    // rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define embeddedKafka by class annotation, and define topics using spEL there:

```java
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = {"${my.topic1}", "${my.topic2}"})
```

Or you can define embededKafka as a separate bean in any config class, with all the properties you need.

And don't forget to autowire it.

```java
@Autowired
private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka;
```